# suitable omiyage

Tags: etiquette, gifts, japan

I graduated from Japan three years ago. I am now going in a visit, and will meet my professor and previous colleagues at one gathering. What is an appropriate protocol for omiyage in similar situation?

Comment: Welcome to AC.SE. How specific is this to academia? Would it be a better fit (i.e., more likely for you to get a good answer) at workplace.se?

Comment: I'd suggest: i) ask this at https://www.reddit.com/r/japan/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/japanlife/. Chance is you'll get more attention from someone familiar with the culture, ii) ask a few of your Japanese friends (you did make some, right?) for pointers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not specific to academia.

Comment: @Fomite are you familiar enough with Japanese culture to know that there are not specific aspects of omiyage unique to academia?

Comment: @StrongBad I did a more through search to see if there was any evidence of academia-specific norms than I would for most questions, and found none. Absent that, and with no articulation of why it should be in either the question or comments, I voted to close. If this turns out to be incorrect, we have the reopen mechanism to address such issues.

Comment: @StrongBad Beyond that in the general case, if "Are you enough of an expert to prove a negative" is going to be a threshold for voting to close a question, that's going to go interesting places...after all, there could always be regional, school, departmental or individual lab norms...

Comment: @Fomite wasn't really trying to go anywhere, I just don't know anything about omiyage and wanted to make sure people were not just running with my comment. I think we are good to migrate to workplace.se